# How can I access an object's property from the PropertyInfo?

Tags: c#, reflection, propertyinfo, getproperties

When I foreach through an object's properties and end up with a PropertyInfo, how can I access the actual property of the object?

```
@foreach(var propertyInfo in Model.Entity.GetType().GetProperties()) {
    if (propertyInfo.PropertyType != typeof(string) &&
        propertyInfo.PropertyType.GetInterface(typeof(IEnumerable<>).Name) != null) {
        <div>
            @foreach(var item in propertyInfo/*Need Actual Property Here*/) {
                @Html.Action("Edit", new { Id = item.Id, typeName = "Item" });
            }
        </div>;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `name`? The `value`? what?

Comment: @hunter I new it wasn't the `name` but I did not know `value` was the term for what I wanted. It makes sense to me now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you need an instance to call it on - presumably that's `Model.Entity` in this case. You need [the `GetValue` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b05d59ty.aspx). However, it's going to be quite tricky - because you need two things:

- You need the value to be iterable by `foreach`
- You need each `item` to have an `Id` property.

If you're using C# 4 and .NET 4, you can use dynamic typing to make it a bit simpler:

```
IEnumerable values = (IEnumerable) propertyInfo.GetValue(Model.Entity, null);
@foreach(dynamic item in values) {
    @Html.Action("Edit", new { Id = item.Id, typeName = "Item" });
}
```

Or even:

```
dynamic values = propertyInfo.GetValue(Model.Entity, null);
@foreach(dynamic item in values) {
    @Html.Action("Edit", new { Id = item.Id, typeName = "Item" });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You saved me a lot of time by answering questions I didn't even know I would soon have to ask next.

Answer (score 1):

When you say get the "actual property of the object" if you are referring to the value of the property then you can do something like below.

```
var item = in propertyInfo.GetValue(Model.Entity, null);
```

However if you don't have the proper type resolved (which should be object in the above example using `var` for inference) you will not be able to access the `Id` property of the value without further reflection or a different dynamic method for accessing the data.

Edit: modified the example not to be in the `foreach` as @Jon Skeet pointed out it wouldn't compile without the cast and this is moreover to demonstrate retrieving a value from `PropertyInfo`

Comment: That's not going to compile - the foreach statement needs something iterable, and we need `item.Id` to be valid.

Comment: @Quintin Thank you for your very quick reply.